# Recommendations required for communication between Eclipse RCP client and Server

Tags: spring, osgi, eclipse-rcp

I want some recommendation on best way to communicate RCP thick client and a set of business functionality implemented in Spring on the server side. Please provide urls on the net wherever possible. 
I would prefer to pass domain objects directly between the two. 
Is osgi a good option for me?

Comment: Why do you think OSGi is relevant?

Comment: me not sure. i am just trying to evaluate the options.

Comment: By using RCP he is running OSGi on the client side so it is natural for one to wonder if it should be used on the server side also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For RESTful web services you could use the [Jersey client library](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#client-api). If your exchange format is XML it is really easy to exchange your objects (see [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html) for a tutorial).

Generally, you can use any client library depending on you exchange protocol also in an Eclipse RCP app (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594024/how-to-create-osgi-bundle-from-jar-library) how to convert a jar into an OSGI bundle).