# Creating Eclipse plugins from existing jars in an automated build

Tags: eclipse-plugin, build-automation, eclipse-pde, tycho

I want to make the build process for my Eclipse RCP plugin fully automatic. It has some third-party jar dependencies (available from Maven repositories) which are not distributed as OSGi bundles, and currently I use the "Eclipse plugin from existing JAR archives" wizard to convert them manually. Can PDEBuild or Maven/Tycho (or perhaps some other build system) do it as a step of the build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Peter Tillemans mentioned the [PAX wrap jar](http://www.ops4j.org/projects/pax/construct/help/wrap-jar.html) command in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594024/how-to-create-osgi-bundle-from-jar-library)

The [Maven bundle plugin](http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/develop-osgi-bundles-using-maven-bundle-plugin) from Apache Felix may be worth a look, too.

Maybe the [Bundlor tool](http://static.springsource.org/s2-bundlor/1.0.x/user-guide/htmlsingle/user-guide.html#introduction) from SpringSource can handle the creation of osgi bundles from jar, too.

Comment: once you have an OSGi bundle available as maven artifact, check https://docs.sonatype.org/display/TYCHO/Dependency+on+pom-first+artifacts on how to use them from tycho.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout the p2-maven-plugin developed by me. It's an open-source, community-friendly plugin that handles:

- the wrap of the jars that are not OSGi bundles (that's fully customizable)
- the generation a fully functional p2-update site that may be consumed in the Eclipse PDE
- the generation of the corresponding source bundles (it generates source bundles for all the bundles)

Details and the documentation could be find here: http://projects.reficio.org/p2-maven-plugin/manual.html

Sample usage:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.reficio</groupId>
    <artifactId>p2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <configuration>
                <artifacts>
                    <!-- specify your depencies here -->
                    <!-- groupId:artifactId:version -->
                    <artifact><id>commons-io:commons-io:2.1</id></artifact>
                    <artifact><id>commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4</id></artifact>
                    <artifact><id>commons-lang:commons-lang:2.5</id></artifact>
                    <artifact><id>commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6</id></artifact>
                    <artifact><id>org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1</id></artifact>
                </artifacts>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the differences between the thirdparty jar and its bundled equivalence. It's just an additional plugin.xml and a few extra lines in the manifest.

Write your own code for bundling jars.

Comment: I disagree: Writing a correct OSGi manifest for a Java library is hard in most cases.