# Eclipse PDE/OSGi: Reflections Library not finding packages

Tags: eclipse, reflection, eclipse-plugin, osgi

The org.reflections library does not function correctly when it's used inside an Eclipse Plugin project.

For instance, the following code should return all classes of a given subtype in a given package:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.package");
Set<Class<? extends Subtype>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Subtype.class);
```

When running the project as a Plugin, `classes` will be empty. Inserting a main() and running it as a normal Java application will correctly return the expected classes.

I've tried to:

```
Include the Reflections library as a normal third-party jar dependency

Include the Reflections library as an OSGi bundle (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339845/reflections-library-not-working-when-used-in-an-eclipse-plug-in)
```

Edit: current process (based on stackoverflow answer above):

1) New Plugin-Project (OSGIReflections called) based on external JARs (Reflections and Javassist)

2) In my actual Plugin-project (X) I add a dependency on OSGIReflections in Dependencies -> Required Plug-ins

2.a) If I run the project as normal java app: Reflections is working

2.b) If I run the project as plugin project: Reflections is not working

3) Create the BundleUrlType class

4) How do I activate this BundleUrlType? In my plugin Activator I call the createReflections(context.getBundle()) function but I do not have a .data file. How do I generate that?

Comment: The second link to [Include the Reflections library as an OSGi bundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339845/reflections-library-not-working-when-used-in-an-eclipse-plug-in) looks pretty good. Try following those instructions. If they don't work, give details of what went wrong.

Comment: @NeilBartlett This is my process:

1) New Plugin-Project (OSGIReflections called) based on external JARs (Reflections and Javassist)
2) In my actual Plugin-project (X)  I add a dependency on OSGIReflections in Dependencies -> Required Plug-ins 
2.a) If I run the project as normal java app: Reflections is working
2.b) If I run the project as plugin project: Reflections is not working
3) Create the BundleUrlType class 
4) How do I activate this BundleUrlType? In my plugin Activator I call the createReflections(context.getBundle()) function but I do not have a .data file. How do I generate that?

Comment: I don't know what a `.data` file is. It's not needed for OSGi, is it something required by the Reflections library? If so, check the docs for Reflections.

Comment: Oh I see, `reflectiveplugin.data` is not a file, it's a package name. I think it's where the author of that SO answer put his sample classes.

Comment: have you tried using "Eclipse-RegisterBuddy: bundle-symbolic-name" header?

Answer (score 0):

I know that's pretty old question, but for all struggling with OSGi with probably all suggestions on SO not working I have small tip:

My case: Reflections 0.9.8 (later versions should work similar) on a Fabric8 container.

TL;DR: The key was make `org.osgi.framework.Bundle` to work as `java.lang.ClassLoader` and passed to Reflections instance.

During debugging sessions I've found that `org.reflections.util.ClasspathHelper` finds two `ClassLoaders` by default as a result of:

- `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();`

  containing only `org.osgi.*` and `org.apache.karaf.*` packages
- `Reflections.class.getClassLoader();`

  containing `org.reflections.*` package

so there is no place with user created code. I've found that both `ClassLoader` and `Bundle` have two common methods:

```java
    Class<?> loadClass(String var1) throws ClassNotFoundException;

    Enumeration<URL> getResources(String var1) throws IOException;
```

so I've created `ClassLoader` with delegation to `Bundle`:

```java
public class BundleClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    private final Bundle bundle;

    public BundleClassLoader(Bundle bundle) {
        this.bundle = bundle;
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<URL> getResources(String name) throws IOException {
        return bundle.getResources(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return bundle.loadClass(name);
    }

}
```

and passed it to `Reflections` instance:

```java
new Reflections(packageName, new BundleClassLoader(bundleContext.getBundle()), new SubTypesScanner(false));
```

*edit:* As I found out later, I still needed own implementation of `UrlType` that matches OSGi implementation. In my case, despite of using *fixed* version of Reflections (`mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.reflections/0.9.8_1` which has its own bundle protocol implementation) I needed to add implementation based on example in answer from [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8451270) changing `BUNDLE_PROTOCOL` from `bundleresource` to `bundle`.