# OSGI Bundle not working with Reflections

Tags: apache, nexus

I am working with an OSGI Bundle, where we use reflections to load classes for a particular annotation from within a sub jar, so my structure is somewhat like this:

> - abc.jar
>
>   > - libs
>   > - reflections.jar
>   > - ab.jar
>   > - cd.jar

While doing the reflections from with ab.jar, we are facing some issues and we get the following error:

```
2017-04-28 15:33:02,374+0530 WARN  [MessageConsumer-hosted.durable] *SYSTEM org.reflections.Reflections - could not create Dir using bundle from url bundle://186.0:3/. skipping.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.reflections.vfs.Vfs$DefaultUrlTypes$6.createDir(Vfs.java:274) [org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.eiffel-nexus-plugin:3.2.1.01]
    at org.reflections.vfs.Vfs.fromURL(Vfs.java:98) [org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.eiffel-nexus-plugin:3.2.1.01]
    at org.reflections.vfs.Vfs.fromURL(Vfs.java:90) [org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.eiffel-nexus-plugin:3.2.1.01]
    at org.reflections.Reflections.scan(Reflections.java:236) [org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.eiffel-nexus-plugin:3.2.1.01]
    at org.reflections.Reflections.scan(Reflections.java:203) [org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.eiffel-nexus-plugin:3.2.1.01]
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:128) [org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.eiffel-nexus-plugin:3.2.1.01]
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:169) [org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.eiffel-nexus-plugin:3.2.1.01]
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:142) [org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.eiffel-nexus-plugin:3.2.1.01]
    at com.message.MessagingVersion.findEventImplementations(MessagingVersion.java:120) [org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.eiffel-nexus-plugin:3.2.1.01]
    at com.message.MessagingVersion.getEventImplementations(MessagingVersion.java:82) [org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.eiffel-nexus-plugin:3.2.1.01]
org.reflections.Reflections - could not create Dir using commons_vfs2 from url bundle://186.0:3/. skipping.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/vfs2/VFS
    at org.reflections.vfs.Vfs$DefaultUrlTypes$7.matches(Vfs.java:281) [org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.eiffel-nexus-plugin:3.2.1.01]
    at org.reflections.vfs.Vfs.fromURL(Vfs.java:97) [org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.eiffel-nexus-plugin:3.2.1.01]
    at org.reflections.vfs.Vfs.fromURL(Vfs.java:90) [org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.eiffel-nexus-plugin:3.2.1.01]
    at org.reflections.Reflections.scan(Reflections.java:236) [org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.eiffel-nexus-plugin:3.2.1.01]
    at org.reflections.Reflections.scan(Reflections.java:203) [org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.eiffel-nexus-plugin:3.2.1.01]
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:128) [org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.eiffel-nexus-plugin:3.2.1.01]
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:169) [org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.eiffel-nexus-plugin:3.2.1.01]
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:142) [org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.eiffel-nexus-plugin:3.2.1.01]
    at 

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.vfs2.VFS not found by org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.eiffel-nexus-plugin [186]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1574) [na:na]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:79) [na:na]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2018) [na:na]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_102]
... 18 common frames omitted
```

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: Incomplete logs and code to know the cause

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8339845/2448440