# Using EclipseLink JPA in OSGI (Karaf)

Tags: jpa, osgi, eclipselink, karaf, eclipse-gemini

I am using EclipseLink as my JPA implementation(in KARAF).And following jars are used:-

```
install -s mvn:org.eclipse.persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.antlr/2.5.0
install -s mvn:org.eclipse.persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.asm/2.5.0
install -s mvn:org.eclipse.persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.core/2.5.0
install -s mvn:org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec/1.1
install -s mvn:org.osgi/org.osgi.compendium/4.2.0
install -s mvn:org.osgi/org.osgi.enterprise/4.2.0
org.eclipse.gemini.dbaccess.derby_1.0.0.M1-incubation.jar
org.eclipse.gemini.jpa.weaving_1.0.0.RC1.jar
org.eclipse.gemini.jpa_1.0.0.RC1.jar
```

My `persistence.xml` is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="resource" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>myPkg.entity.Resource</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" 
                /> <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:DB;create=true" 
                />

            <!-- <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/D:\DB;create=true" /> -->


            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="test" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="test" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="OFF" />

            <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
                value="database" />
            <property name="connection.autocommit" value="false" />
            <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode" value="commit" /> 
            <!-- <property name="eclipselink.allow-zero-id" value="true"/> -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

But the `gemini.dbaccess.derby_1.0.0.M1-incubation` jar remians in Installed state as well as the `gemini.jpa.weaving jar` remains in resolved state.

Restarting the `gemini.dbaccess.derby_1.0.0.M1-incubation` gives the following error:-

```
Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: org.apache.derby.client.am; version="0.0.0"
```

And my application gives the following error:-

```
Could not find data source factory in registry: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
```

I am new to using eclipseLink in OSGI ,what am i missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache karaf 4.0.0 has been released,this version of karaf provides eclipseLink support.

```
feature:install eclipselink
```

Therefore there is no need to use external adapters for using eclipseLink

Comment: What repository has the eclipseLink feature?

Comment: The feature:install command is case sensitive - feature:install eclipselink

Answer (score 0):

Here is the content of the manifest of *org.eclipse.gemini.dbaccess.derby_1.0.0.M1-incubation.jar*:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Gemini DBAccess (Incubation)
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.gemini.dbaccess.derby
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.M1-incubation
Bundle-Activator: org.eclipse.gemini.dbaccess.derby.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: Oracle Corporation
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5
Import-Package: javax.sql,
org.apache.derby.client.am,
org.apache.derby.jdbc,
org.osgi.framework;version="[1.3,2)",
org.osgi.service.jdbc;version="[1.0,2.0)"
```

There are still two unresolved dependencies on [Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/) binaries:

- org.apache.derby.client.am
- org.apache.derby.jdbc

Both lack a version number, this is why the message states *0.0.0*.

The two packages are part of the *derbyclient.jar* file available as an OSGi bundle in the Derby binaries.  The problem is that the *Export-Package* clause of this bundle only exposes the *org.apache.derby.jdbc* package.

A simple solution is the [*SpringSource*-packaged bundle](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.org.apache.derby.client&version=10.5.1000001.764942): it exposes the two required packages. Beware, it has an additional dependency on the [Java transaction API](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.javax.transaction&version=1.1.0).

Comment: So what sholud i do..? my Application is not running

Comment: Download the derby archive and deploy the *derbyclient.jar* file in your container. It will provide the JDBC component as an exported package (*Export-Package* clause in the JAR MANIFEST.MF). This should solve your error. You could then face a dependency problem on the *org.apache.derby.client.am* package as it is available in the classpath but not exposed in the *Export-Package* clause. In such a case, you could have to re-package the bundle, but this is [another story](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9821072/1207019).

Comment: The [*SpringSource*-packaged bundle](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.org.apache.derby.client&version=10.5.1000001.764942) is ready to use: it exposes the two required packages.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you have the regions feature installed with Karaf, cause if you're using a version < 4 (isn't released yet), the Apache Aries Blueprint implementation is installed by default. So if you want to stick to Gemini, this will interfere. Therefore make sure you have Regions installed. Second I think there is a feature around for installing the eclipse-link bundles. Might want to take a look at it to get the right bundles aligned.

If you would stick to the Aries Blueprint impl, then it's even simpler. Just install the following features:

```
feature:install jpa jta jndi
```

and if you want to use the Derby, might also want to install the **jdbc** feature. This will give you a bunch of commands to use to connect to a db and/or create a datasource. If you use the datasource commands, you're able to create a datasource for derby database which will install the correct working derby client jars if needed.